# Why do I get an empty 200 OK response when uploading a file to a shared Google Drive folder when using a service account?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to use a Service Account to upload a file into a shared Google Drive folder, using Google Drive API v3 and the .Net client. The service account is added to the folder and "Can organise, add and edit". And if I do a list request I get the folder back (so I know the service account authentication works and that it at least has access to the shared folder).

If I try to upload a file though, I get a 200 response (so no error) but with an empty ResponseBody. And if I list again, the file isn't there. I don't understand what this means or why it is happening and can't find any information about this situation anywhere.

Here's my upload code. [PARENT_ID] is the ID of the shared folder and I've got the content of the CSV file I'm uploading and converted into bytes to put into the stream I've then sent.

```
using (var driveService = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = googleCredential.CreateScoped(DriveService.Scope.Drive),
    ApplicationName = "FunctionApp"
}))
    {
    File fileMetadata = new File()
    {
        Name = "FileName",
        MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
        Parents = new List<string>() { "[PARENT_ID]" }
    };

    FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
    using (var csvStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        csvStream.Write(csvBytes);
        request = driveService.Files.Create(
            fileMetadata, csvStream, "text/csv");
    }
    request.Fields = "id";
    request.Upload();
    var file = request.ResponseBody;
    Console.WriteLine("File ID: " + file.Id);
}
```

The file variable is always null so obviously file.Id throws a NullReferenceException.

I've been staring at this for hours but have not been able to work out what is wrong. Any ideas?

I've tried saving the csv string to a file a then reading it in a file stream (closer to the example at the bottom of https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#import_to_google_docs_types_) but this yields the same result.

Note: I've been able to create a file in the same folder using the "Try this API" tool on https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create using the parameters the same as what I pass in the metadata here, but of course that doesn't use a service account and doesn't pass any actual data to the file.

Comment: I would like to ask you some questions: 1. Are you able to create with the service account an empty file / file with a dummy content succesfully? Are you able to create file programmatically withour a service account? 3.Are you intending to use Drive v3 or v2?

Comment: @ziganotschka
1. I just tried using Create(File) to create a request (rather than Create(File, Stream, String) that I've used above. This works! But is empty.
2. I haven't tried without a service account and trying would take more significant changes and I don't have time at the moment.
3. Sorry, I should've made clear this is v3.

Comment: This sounds like a problem with the conversion of the CSV data. Did I understand it right that if you save your CSV as a "csv" file on your hard drive and then create the stream as suggested in the Google Documentation with `using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream("files/report.csv",
                        System.IO.FileMode.Open))` - it does not work for you?

Comment: Something that drew my attention is that the method `MemoryStream.Write` expects three parameters - buffer, offset and count, and you only specify the first one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.write?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @ziganotska, I have tried doing it as a file stream, yes and I got the same result, so I’m not convinced it’s just that the memory stream was wrong.

Comment: I’m not sure about MemoryStream.Write, I’ll have to check this when I’m back at my computer, but it does compile!

Comment: It does not compile if you add and offset and count? Something like `csvStream.Write(csvBytes, 0, csvBytes.Length);`?

Comment: No, that also does compile, but makes no difference to the result :(

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with your request, then only two things I can suggest you: 1. Just on the off chance there is a problem with your CSV stream - try to create a text file first with `MimeType = "text/csv"` instead of ` MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"`. Also, try to create a spreadsheet with a different content. 2. Even if it requires code modification - create a file without the service account: When a file is successfully created, but cannot be found - in most cases it is because it has been created on the drive of the service account.

Comment: I tried changing the MimeType - no change. Interestingly if I use `driveService.Files.Create(fileMetadata);`, ie the overload that doesn't upload any content, this works and I have an empty file in the folder I expect. So I do not think it is an issue with the file being in the service account's own drive.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @JonSkeet for the solution on GitHub (https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1490)

The problem was that the stream was being disposed before the upload (ie after the `using`). The code change was to not use a `using` at all.

```cs
var csvStream = new MemoryStream(csvBytes);
request = driveService.Files.Create(fileMetadata, csvStream, "text/csv");
var result = request.Upload();
```

This did a successful upload as expected.

This also didn't use the `request.Fields` although this could maybe have been left in.